# AngularJS equivalent to jQuery toggle show/hide a section

Tags: javascript, angularjs

First of, yes I've tried googling this but it's still hard to find information about AngularJS.

I want to preform a simple task of opening sections based on what button is pushed in the form. I want only one section to be open at anytime and maybe a default one (haven't decided).
It would also be nice if the button you click will be classed "btn-primary" for bootstrap. So this is the html

```
<form>
    <input type="button" id="show-section1" value="Section 1" />
    <input type="button" id="show-section2" value="Section 2" />
    <input type="button" id="show-section3" value="Section 3" />
</form>
<section id="section1">blah</section>
<section id="section2">blah2</section>
<section id="section3">blah3</section>
```

In jQuery I would do something like this (simplified and not the best solution just to explain):

```
$('section').hide();
$('#show-section1').click(function() {
    $('section').hide();
    $('#section1').show();
});
etc
```

I've done this once before but I can't remember how, I remember it was very few lines of code though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just need one at a time, you can use this : http://jsfiddle.net/jHhMv/3/

JS :

```
'use strict';

var App=angular.module('myApp',[]);

function Ctrl($scope){
    var section = 1;

    $scope.section = function (id) {
        section = id;   
    };

    $scope.is = function (id) {
        return section == id;
    };
}
```

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
<form>
    <input type="button" id="show-section1" value="Section 1" ng-click="section(1)" ng-class="{'btn-primary': is(1)}" />
    <input type="button" id="show-section2" value="Section 2" ng-click="section(2)" ng-class="{'btn-primary': is(2)}" />
    <input type="button" id="show-section3" value="Section 3" ng-click="section(3)" ng-class="{'btn-primary': is(3)}" />
</form>
<section id="section1" ng-show="is(1)">blah</section>
<section id="section2" ng-show="is(2)">blah2</section>
<section id="section3" ng-show="is(3)">blah3</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you define 'myApp' ? :S

Comment: that's just a module name. You can put "OZZIE" there if you want

Comment: +1, I like this solution because it also works with dynamic HTML, as in my scenario. The ids in my case are generated on the fly and can't be hardcoded into the html. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Take a Look http://jsfiddle.net/mahbub/jHhMv/

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
<form>
    <input type="button" id="show-section1" value="Section 1" ng-click="section1=!section1" />
    <input type="button" id="show-section2" value="Section 2" ng-click="section2=!section2" />
    <input type="button" id="show-section3" value="Section 3" ng-click="section3=!section3" />
</form>
<section id="section1" ng-show="section1">blah</section>
<section id="section2" ng-show="section2">blah2</section>
<section id="section3" ng-show="section3">blah3</section>
</div>


'use strict';

var App=angular.module('myApp',[]);

function Ctrl($scope){

}
```

Comment: It's just a demonstration about for show hide. For your case Angular isn't quite necessary IMHO.

Comment: OP: "I want only one section to be open at anytime".  Your solution allows multiple to be open at once.

Answer (score 3):

Plenty of ways. One of them (using AngularUI):

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="AppController">

    <button ng-click="setActive('section1')" ng-class="{'btn btn-primary': active.section1}">Section 1</button>
    <button ng-click="setActive('section2')" ng-class="{'btn btn-primary': active.section2}">Section 2</button>
    <button ng-click="setActive('section3')" ng-class="{'btn btn-primary': active.section3}">Section 3</button>

    <section id="section1" ui-toggle="active.section1">blah</section>
    <section id="section2" ui-toggle="active.section2">blah2</section>
    <section id="section3" ui-toggle="active.section3">blah3</section>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-show {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.ui-hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

JS:

```
app.controller('AppController',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.active = {section1: true};
    $scope.setActive = function(section){
      $scope.active = {};
      $scope.active[section] = true;
    };
  }
);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5NoBbWhZFDDzxZ0I9865)

Comment: All I get is: "Error: Argument 'AppController' is not a function, got undefined"

Comment: What should ``var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui']);`` be? Another answer here uses 'myApp' but where do I set that? I have <html ng-app> :S

Comment: Okay finally changed your code into something I recognise from the docs and then it works, thanks anyway! ``function ToggleSectionController($scope) {
 //$scope.active = {section1: true};
 $scope.setActive = function(section) { ...``